# Is it okay if I don't travel to Canada during the dates specified in a visa application?

Tags: visas, canada, tourist-visas

The form (5257e, I believe) for a Canadian visa application asks to indicate "how long I plan to stay" (from ... to ...) and "Name, address and relationship of any person(s) or institution(s) I will visit" (I suppose in my case this would be a hotel name and address). Is it okay if I end up not traveling to Canada during the dates I indicate (and if instead I travel a few months after that date) and/or not staying in the hotel I indicate?

Comment: often the visa is granted for say, 90 days from day X.  And it'll expire on day Y.  So it depends how long afterwards you're going?

Comment: @MarkMayo As far as I know, Canadian multiple-entry visas are valid for up to 10 years or one month before the passport expires, whichever is shorter (from the official website). And from the statistics I've seen, "up to" can be omitted.