# Specifying the visit date for Canada visitor visa

Tags: visas, canada

I'm applying for Canada visitor visa from Iran. I have an invitation letter and other documents from my relative that shows they are willing and able to host me. Somewhere in the personal information form, asks the date I'm planning to visit. Since I'm not sure about it (I may postpone my travel), I wanted to know how important is that date.

To make it clear, I'm not asking if I can visit after my visa has expired. My travel date could vary within the time my visa is valid.

It made me worry since I saw this paragraph on ["Applying for visitor visa"](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/application/application-forms-guides/guide-5256-applying-visitor-visa-temporary-resident-visa.html) page:

> If there has been a change in circumstances between the dates of your application for a visa and your arrival in Canada, or if subsequent information is given which was not originally available to the visa office, you may be refused entry.

So I have three related questions:

1. If I get my visa and I enter Canada on a different date than I specified, how probable is that the officer would reject me?
2. Should the date be specified in my invitation letter or better not to (only include period e.g. 1 month)?
3. Is it necessary to provide my airline ticket reservation when applying (considering I'm not certain about the date I'm planning to visit)

Comment: I [asked](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/144318/is-it-okay-if-i-dont-travel-to-canada-during-the-dates-specified-in-a-visa-appl) a similar question some time ago.  I was unsure about the dates, so to be safe, I indicated 3 possible intervals during which I may visit Canada in my "travel plans" (one of the statements you're asked to submit). Regarding your third question, when I was applying online, I wasn't asked to submit any tickets.

Comment: @user77409 Thanks for your comment. have you got your visa yet? Is it a multiple entry?

Comment: @ foadk, yes and yes.